# Select Top (some number) with UNION ALL and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to pull back the top five instances of certain records loaded into a table.  It is important to note that I am trying to get my results out of the same table and I think there is a problem that I can't quite figure out related to the fact that this is one table.  Here is the example of my query:

```
Select * From (
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 1 Order By JobID DESC
UNION ALL
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 2 Order By JobID DESC
UNION ALL
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 3 Order By JobID DESC
UNION ALL
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 4 Order By JobID DESC
UNION ALL
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 5 Order By JobID DESC
UNION ALL
Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobTypeID = 6 Order By JobID DESC
) As UnionTable
```

When I run this is SQL Server I only get 9 records when I know in fact that there should be 30.  How can I make sure that I pull back all of the correct records?  Do I need to use a Group By clause in each subquery?

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 5 jobs for *each* `JobID`?

Comment: Following on from Nick Craver, I'd run each one individually. And did you mean ORDER BY JobID too?

Comment: Does each Job Id have atleast 5 records, only then it will return 30.

Comment: What version of SQL Server and what are you actually trying to do? e.g. for the part `Select Top 5 JobID From Jobs Where JobID = 1 Order By JobID DESC` the JobId will be 1 for all these records and so the Order By will be arbitrary. You will just get any 5 records with that jobid. (But you're only selecting `JobID` anyway so I guess that makes no difference!)

Comment: Version of SQL Server is 2005

Comment: I'd use a CTE then as in gbn's answer.

Comment: Your query is correct for the stated problem... Either there are only 9 records, or your "example query" isn't the same as the one you're actually using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More elegant..

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
         JobID, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobTypeID ORDER BY JobID /* eh? */ DESC) AS rank
    FROM
         Jobs WHERE JobTypeID BETWEEN 1 AND 6
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rank <= 5
```

<strike>Why do you have both WHERE and ORDER by JobID? This makes the ORDER BY clause meaningless...</strike>

Comment: Please see my edit to the query above, I wrote it too hastily.  Thanks for pointing out that error.

Answer (score 1):

Run each `SELECT` statement separately and see if you get 5 rows for each

Run this to see the count for each, second column returned will be the JobID

```
Select COUNT(*),1 From Jobs Where JobID = 1 
UNION ALL
Select COUNT(*),2 From Jobs Where JobID = 2 
UNION ALL
Select COUNT(*),3 From Jobs Where JobID = 3 
UNION ALL
Select COUNT(*),4 From Jobs Where JobID = 4 
UNION ALL
Select COUNT(*),5 From Jobs Where JobID = 5 
UNION ALL
Select COUNT(*),6 From Jobs Where JobID = 6
```

you can also run it like this

```
Select COUNT(*),JobID
 From Jobs 
 Where JobID between 1 and 6 
 GROUP By JobID
```

Comment: I do not actually, could this affect why I am not getting all of the results that I expect?  In otherwords, for jobID = 1 I know that I am supposed to get 5 results back, and when I run the query by itself I DO get the results back.  However when I run the entire query listed above I get 5 totally different rows.

Comment: what is the output that you get, should be 6 rows